# How to compile Unity source code without downloading the entire engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made a school project in `Unity`, created the executable and made a `ZIP` along with the sources (including `.sln` generated by `Unity`).

Now, my teacher asked that he want to compile the source and check if it works and I really don't want to tell him that he has to download the entire 3gb package.

Is there any way to download requires classes/libs/assemblies and install them on `Windows` so the `.sln` will compile and generate the win executable?

Comment: If you have a .exe you should just be able to run the application, no? Or do you mean your teacher wants to view the code?

Comment: Not sure you can do that because it's not just compiling the code, but also building up all the levels and so on. Plus Unity comes with some custom libraries, which you'll need to compile the code anyway. You could send your professor the built game executable, but if they want to do it themselves, whole unity software is required.

Comment: If all you need to do is view the code.. you can possibly use Visual Studio Code : https://code.visualstudio.com/ , which is much smaller than the Unity Engine

Comment: He has the .exe, it works on his PC, but he wants to compile the code (with Visual Studio) and create his own exe. I already wrote in the documentation that this requires a Unity Engine, but I don't want to point that he didn't read the doc and risk the rejection of the project.

Comment: Sorry.. but he's going to have to download Unity or the extension built into Visual Studio to compile Unity Projects..which is basically downloading the engine still

Comment: And if Unity downloaded and installed - will the .sln compile without linking any libraries etc? Will VS find the Unity folder on it's own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compile a Unity project, you need to download and install the Unity editor; there's no way around that (make sure they download the same version because there might be differences in the APIs). The one thing you can do to make things a bit easier would be to delete the "*Library*" folder inside of your project before you zip it. This is a cached collection of game-ready data that's derived from your assets and their corresponding meta files; it will be re-generated if it's missing.